# Where can I find a copy of the wddx.dtd?

Tags: xml, dom, xml-parsing, dtd, wddx

I have a project that involves parsing wddx webservice responses.  The DOM DocumentBuilder is throwing an exception that the XML is malformed as it does not reference a dtd.  I inserted a DOCTYPE statement and now it is throwing an exception malformed - cannot find the protocol.  I am quite certain it is my reference to the DTD and I now need a local copy.  I thought it would be a simple surf to get the DTD from wddx.org, however, that has not been successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it is up-to-date, but I found [this reference on xml.coverpages.org](http://xml.coverpages.org/wddx0090-dtd-19980928.txt), which linked to [a local archive copy of the DTD](http://xml.coverpages.org/wddx0090-dtd-19980928.txt)

> WDDX DTD From: 
>   http://www.codebits.com/wddx/wddx_0090.dtd.txt
>   Date:  1998-09-28

```
<!-- ************************************************************************
     WDDX DTD:

     Author: Simeon Simeonov (simeons@allaire.com)

     Copyright (c) 1998 Allaire Corp. http://www.allaire.com
-->

<!-- ************************************************************************
     Introductory Notes:


     What is WDDX:

     WDDX stands for Web Distributed Data eXchange. WDDX is a mechanism for
     exchanging complex data structures between programming languages. It
     has been designed with web applications in mind. WDDX consists of a 
     language-independent representation of instantiated data based on 
     XML 1.0 (which is defined using this DTD) and a set of serializer/
     deserializer modules for every language/technology that uses WDDX.

     The WDDX DTD:

     The WDDX DTD can be used to validate WDDX packets. Packets are
     representations of instantiated data structures in programming 
     languages. The following is an example of a WDDX packet:

          <?xml version='1.0'?>
          <!DOCTYPE wddxPacket SYSTEM 'wddx_0090.dtd'>
          <wddxPacket version='0.9'>
             <header/>
             <data>
                 <struct>
                     <var name='s'>
                         <string>a string</string>
                     </var>
                     <var name='n'>
                         <number>-12.456</number>
                     </var>
                     <var name='d'>
                         <dateTime>1998-06-12T04:32:12</dateTime>
                     </var>
                     <var name='b'>
                         <boolean value='true'/>
                     </var>
                     <var name='a'>
                         <array length='2'>
                             <number>10</number>
                             <string>second element</string>
                         </array>
                     </var>
                     <var name='obj'>
                         <struct>
                             <var name='s'>
                                 <string>a string</string>
                             </var>
                             <var name='n'>
                                 <number>-12.456</number>
                             </var>
                         </struct>
                     </var>
                     <var name='r'>
                        <recordset rowCount='2' fieldNames='NAME,AGE'>
                            <field name='NAME'>
                                <string>John Doe</string>
                                <string>Jane Doe</string>
                            </field>
                            <field name='AGE'>
                                <number>34</number>
                                <number>31</number>
                            </field>
                        </recordset>
                     </var>
                 </struct>
             </data>
         </wddxPacket>

     It defines a root level object that is a structure (also known as 
     an associative array) of six properties:

     - s which is the string 'a string',
     - n which is the number -12.456,
     - d which is the date-time value June 12, 1998 4:32:12am,
     - b which is the boolean value true,
     - a which is an array of two elements (10 and 'second element'),
     - obj which is a structure with two properties s and n, and
     - r which is a recordset of two rows with fields NAME and AGE.

     Basic data types:

     WDDX supports the following basic data types: boolean (true/false), 
     number, date-time, and string. 

     Numbers are internally represented with floating point numbers. Because 
     of differences between WDDX-enabled languages, the range of numbers has 
     been restricted to 3.4E+/-38. The precision has been restricted to 7 
     digits after the decimal point. These requirements are consistent with 
     a 4-byte floating point representation.

     Date-time values are encoded according to the full form of ISO8601. 
     Timezone information will be successfully parsed and used to convert to
     a local data-time value. Efforts should me made to ensure that the 
     internal representation of date-time values does not suffer from Y2K
     problems and covers a sufficient range of date-time values.

     Strings can be of arbitrary length and must not contain embedded nulls.

     Complex data types:

     WDDX supports the following complex data types: arrays, structures, and 
     recordsets.

     Arrays are integer-indexed collections of objects of arbitrary type. 
     The starting index value is usually 0 with the notable exception of 
     CFML whose arrays have an initial index value of 1. Because of these
     differences working with array indices can lead to non-portable data.

     Structures are string-indexed collections of object of arbitrary type.
     In many languages they are known as associative arrays. Structures
     contain one or more variables. Because some of the languages supported
     by WDDX are not case-sensitive, no two variable names can differ only
     by their case.

     Recordsets are tabular data encapsulations: a set of named fields with 
     the same number of rows of data. Only simple data types can be stored in
     recordsets. For tabular data storage of complex data types, an array of 
     structures should be used. Because some of the languages supported by 
     WDDX are not case-sensitive, no two field names can differ only by 
     their case.

     Data type comparisons:

     The following table compares the basic WDDX data types with those of 
     languages/technologies commonly used on the Web.

     WDDX Type         COM              Java Type           ECMAScript Type   
     **************    *************    ****************    ***************   
     boolean           boolean          boolean             boolean           
     number            float?           float?              number            
     dateTime          DATE             ??                  Date              
     string            BSTR             java.lang.String    string            
     array             VARIANT array    ??                  Array             
     struct            IWDDXStruct      ??                  Object            
     recordset         IWDDXRecordset   ??                  WddxRecordset     


     More on data types:

     WDDX provides no notion of a null object. Null objects should be 
     serialized to empty strings. Upon deserialization it is up to the
     component performing the operation to determine whether and where 
     should empty strings be deserialized to null values. 

     WDDX serializes data using a model of pure aggregation. It has no
     mechanism for handling object references. Aliased references will
     result in multiple object instances being deserialized. WDDX 
     serialization applied to a data structure that has cyclical references
     will most likely result in infinite iteration/recursion, depending on
     the serializer implementation.

-->

<!ELEMENT wddxPacket (header, data)>
<!ATTLIST wddxPacket
          version CDATA #FIXED "0.9">

<!ELEMENT header (comment?)>

<!ELEMENT comment (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT data (boolean | number | dateTime | string | array | struct | recordset)*>

<!ELEMENT boolean EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST boolean 
          value (true | false) #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT string (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT number (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT dateTime (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT array (boolean | number | dateTime | string | array | struct | recordset)*>
<!ATTLIST array 
          length CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT struct (var*)>

<!ELEMENT var (boolean | number | dateTime | string | array | struct | recordset)>
<!ATTLIST var
          name CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT recordset (field*)>       
<!ATTLIST recordset 
          rowCount CDATA #REQUIRED
          fieldNames CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT field (boolean | number | dateTime | string)*>
<!ATTLIST field
          name CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

Comment: THanks Mads.  When I visit those sites, I get a dead link?!?  I have both of them in my history, but either the DTD was no there or the link did a 404 on me ?!??  Thanks for pasting the content, I just created the file.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to jump on an old thread but this kept coming up when I was searching for the wddx.dtd. The version in the previous answer is version 0.9 which probably will not help most people because version 1.0 has been in use for at least 5 years or so.

I am faced with converting an old legacy app which is using wddx for serializing data. I thought I would post it here in case anybody else faced the same issue. A lot of posts here have helped me out greatly in the past so why not return the favour.

In the end I managed to get my hands on the file by using the way back machine (waybackmachine.org) and feeding in this URL - http://www.openwddx.org/downloads/dtd/wddx_dtd_10.txt. When I was trying openwddx.org never worked. All hail the way back machine!

From the [archived copy](http://web.archive.org/web/20041205052934/http://www.openwddx.org/downloads/dtd/wddx_dtd_10.txt):

```
<!-- ************************************************************************
     WDDX DTD

     Editor:               Simeon Simeonov (simeons@allaire.com)

     Contributing authors: Hussain Chinoy (hussain@granularity.com)
                           Nate Weiss (nweiss@icesinc.com)

     Last modified:        October 19, 1999

     Copyright (c) 1998, 1999 Allaire Corp. http://www.allaire.com
-->

<!-- ************************************************************************
     Introductory Notes:


     What is WDDX:

     WDDX stands for Web Distributed Data Exchange. WDDX is a mechanism for
     exchanging complex data structures between application environments. It
     has been designed with web applications in mind. WDDX consists of a 
     language and platform neutral representation of instantiated data based
     on XML 1.0 (which is defined using this DTD) and a set of serializer/
     deserializer modules for every environment that uses WDDX. The process 
     of creating an XML representation of application data is called
     serialization. The process of instantiating application data from a 
     WDDX XML representation is called deserialization.

     WDDX packets:

     The WDDX DTD can be used to validate WDDX packets. Packets are
     representations of instantiated data structures in application 
     environments. The following is an example of a WDDX packet:

         <?xml version='1.0'?>
         <!DOCTYPE wddxPacket SYSTEM 'wddx_0100.dtd'>
         <wddxPacket version='1.0'>
             <header/>
             <data>
                 <struct>
                     <var name='aNull'>
                         <null/>
                     </var>
                     <var name='aString'>
                         <string>a string</string>
                     </var>
                     <var name='aNumber'>
                         <number>-12.456</number>
                     </var>
                     <var name='aDateTime'>
                         <dateTime>1998-06-12T04:32:12</dateTime>
                     </var>
                     <var name='aBoolean'>
                         <boolean value='true'/>
                     </var>
                     <var name='anArray'>
                         <array length='2'>
                             <number>10</number>
                             <string>second element</string>
                        </array>
                     </var>
                     <var name='aBinary'>
                         <binary length='8'>MIIBJASHETASV==</binary>
                     </var>
                     <var name='anObject'>
                         <struct>
                             <var name='s'>
                                 <string>a string</string>
                             </var>
                             <var name='n'>
                                 <number>-12.456</number>
                             </var>
                         </struct>
                     </var>
                     <var name='aRecordset'>
                         <recordset rowCount='2' fieldNames='NAME,AGE'>
                             <field name='NAME'>
                                 <string>John Doe</string>
                                 <string>Jane Doe</string>
                             </field>
                             <field name='AGE'>
                                 <number>34</number>
                                 <number>31</number>
                             </field>
                         </recordset>
                     </var>
                 </struct>
             </data>
         </wddxPacket>

     It defines a root level object that is a structure (also known as 
     an associative array) of eight properties:

     - aNull which is a null value,
     - aString which is the string 'a string',
     - aNumber which is the number -12.456,
     - aDateTime which is the date-time value June 12, 1998 4:32:12am,
     - aBoolean which is the boolean value true,
     - anArray which is an array of two elements (10 and 'second element'),
     - aBinary which contains 8 bytes of binary data encoded in base64,
     - anObject which is a structure with two properties s and n, and
     - aRecordset which is a recordset of two rows with fields NAME and AGE.

     Basic data types:

     WDDX supports the following basic data types: null, boolean (true/false), 
     number, date-time, and string. 

     Null-
     Null values in WDDX are not associated with a type such as number or 
     string. Languages that do not have the concept of a null value should
     deserialize nulls as empty strings.

     Numbers-
     Numbers are internally represented with floating point numbers. Because 
     of differences between WDDX-enabled languages, the range of numbers has 
     been restricted to +/-1.7E+/-308. The precision has been restricted to 
     15 digits after the decimal point. These requirements are consistent 
     with an 8-byte floating-point representation.

     Date-time values-
     Date-time values are encoded according to the full form of ISO8601,
     e.g., 1998-9-15T09:05:32+4:0. Note that single-digit values for months,
     days, hours, minutes, or seconds do not need to be zero-prefixed. 
     While timezone information is optional, it must be successfully parsed
     and used to convert to local date-time values. Efforts should me made 
     to ensure that the internal representation of date-time values does not 
     suffer from Y2K problems and covers a sufficient range of dates. In 
     particular, years must always be represented with four digits.

     Strings-
     Strings can be of arbitrary length and must not contain embedded nulls.
     To facilitate the inclusion of control characters in strings, the
     <string> element can contain <char code='??'/> elements. The value of
     the code attribute is a two-character representation of the UTF-8 hex 
     code for a given control character. For example, <char code='0C'/>
     represents the form feed character. Control characters are characters
     in the UTF-8 range 00-1F. Note that tab (09) and newline (0A) characters
     can be included directly in XML text. The XML 1.0 specification Section
     2.11 requires XML processors to not pass carriage return (0D) characters
     to applications. 

     Note on end-of-line handling-
     End-of-line characters have platform and programming language specific 
     representations. Different application environments may use either a 
     single newline (0A), a single carriage return (0D), or a carriage return 
     and newline combination (0D0A). For the purposes of successful data 
     encoding and translation the elements <char code='0A'/> and 
     <char code='0D'/> must be used to encode newline and carriage return 
     characters when they should be preserved in the deserialized string. 
     Note that Section 2.11 of the XML 1.0 specification requires XML 
     processors to translate all occurrences of carriage returns and the 
     carriage return, newline combination to a single newline character. 
     Therefore, for the purposes of XML, end-of-line is represented by a 
     single newline character.

     Complex data types:

     WDDX supports the following complex data types: arrays, structures,
     recordsets, and binary.

     Arrays-
     Arrays are integer-indexed collections of objects of arbitrary type. 
     The starting index value is usually 0 with the notable exception of 
     CFML whose arrays have an initial index value of 1. Because of these
     differences working with array indices can lead to non-portable data.

     Structures-
     Structures are string-indexed collections of objects of arbitrary type.
     In many languages they are known as associative arrays, dictionaries, or
     maps. Structures contain one or more variables. Because some of the 
     languages supported by WDDX are not case-sensitive, no two variable names
     can differ only by their case. In the case where two variables have the 
     same names or differ only by their case the final deserialized value would
     be the value of the last variable.

     Recordsets-
     Recordsets are tabular data encapsulations: a set of named fields with 
     the same number of rows of data. Only simple data types can be stored in
     recordsets. For tabular data storage of complex data types, an array of 
     structures should be used. Because some of the languages supported by WDDX
     are not case-sensitive, no two field names can differ only by their case.
     In the case where two fields have the same names or differ only by their
     case the final deserialized values will be the values from the last field. 
     Field names must satisfy the regular expression [_A-Za-z][_.0-9A-Za-z]* 
     where the '.' stands for a period, not 'any character'.

     Binary-
     The binary datatype represents strings (blobs) of binary data. The WDDX 
     DTD allows for multiple encodings of binary data. In this version only 
     MIME style base64 encoding is supported by the specification. Optionally,
     the length of the encoded binary object can be provided as a hint to
     WDDX deserializers. It can be used to validate the length of the binary
     object after decoding. It can also be used for efficient allocation of
     memory during the decoding process.

     Data type comparisons:

     The following table compares the basic WDDX data types with those of 
     languages/technologies/specifications commonly used on the Web.

     WDDX            XMLSchema       Java                         ECMAScript     COM Type
     **************  **************  ***************************  *************  ****************  
     null            N/A             null                         null           VT_NULL
     boolean         boolean         java.lang.Boolean            boolean        VT_BOOL         
     number          number          java.lang.Double             number         VT_R8           
     dateTime        dateTime        java.lang.Date               Date           VT_DATE         
     string          string          java.lang.String             string         VT_BSTR         
     array           N/A             java.lang.Vector             Array          VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT
     struct          N/A             java.lang.Hashtable          Object         IWDDXStruct     
     recordset       N/A             com.allaire.util.RecordSet   WddxRecordset  IWDDXRecordset  
     binary          binary          com.allaire.util.Binary      WddxBinary     V_ARRAY | UI1   

     More on data types:

     Reserved properties-
     For the purposes of efficiently implementing WDDX platform modules in
     a variety of languages, and to facilitate the representation of
     arbitrary datatypes, WDDX reserves all object/structure/recordset
     property/var/field names beginning with '_wddx'. (The prefix is case-
     insensitive because some of the languages WDDX works with are case-
     insensitive.) WDDX serializers can treat such names in a special, 
     language and platform specific manner. WDDX deserializers can do the 
     same with the name attributes of the var and field elements.

     Serialization model-
     WDDX serializes data using a model of pure aggregation. It has no 
     mechanism for handling object references. Aliased references will result
     in multiple object instances being deserialized. WDDX serialization 
     applied to a data structure that has cyclical references will most 
     likely result in infinite iteration/recursion, depending on the 
     serializer implementation. Object references support is another area of 
     future investigation.

     Multiple object types-
     WDDX provides no built-in mechanism for representing objects of 
     arbitrary type. This is done on purpose to enable interoperability
     between application environments using a minimal yet functional set of
     datatypes. In some special cases, however, particularly when WDDX is 
     used to exchange data between identical application environments, there
     is a need for preserving object type in the serialization/
     deserialization process. To facilitate this, the top-level elements
     representing all datatypes can have an optional 'type' attribute whose 
     value is platform-specific. Upon serialization this attribute can be 
     used to provide information about the type of the serialized object. If
     provided, the value of this attribute can be used by a deserializer to 
     instantiate a particular type of object. To facilitate the 
     representation of arbitrary objects the _wddx_structAttributes_type 
     property is reserved to contain the value of the type attribute of the 
     struct element. Neither sererializers nor deserializers are required to
     use or populate this reserved property, but it is recommended that they
     provide the capability. However, if they do provide it, it is required 
     (on both sides) that this behavior is optional and that it defaults to 
     "Off".

     DTD verbosity:

     This DTD is purposefully made verbose to aid the readability of WDDX
     packets. If packet size becomes an issue, compressing WDDX packets
     using an HTTP-safe real time compression algorithm is likely to be a
     much more appropriate solution than, for example, a DTD that uses one
     character element and attribute names. Some experiments conducted at
     Allaire suggest that 5 - 15 fold compression rates are achievable.

-->

<!ELEMENT wddxPacket (header, data)>
<!ATTLIST wddxPacket
          version CDATA #FIXED "1.0">

<!ELEMENT header (comment?)>

<!ELEMENT comment (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT data (null | boolean | number | dateTime | string | array | struct | recordset | binary)>

<!ELEMENT null EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST null
          type CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT boolean EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST boolean 
          value (true | false) #REQUIRED
          type CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT string (#PCDATA | char)*>
<!ATTLIST string
          type CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT char EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST char 
          code CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT number (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST number
          type CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT dateTime (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST dateTime
          type CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT array (null | boolean | number | dateTime | string | array | struct | recordset | binary)*>
<!ATTLIST array 
          length CDATA #REQUIRED
          type CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT struct (var*)>
<!ATTLIST struct
          type CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT var (null | boolean | number | dateTime | string | array | struct | recordset | binary)>
<!ATTLIST var
          name CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT recordset (field*)>
<!ATTLIST recordset 
          rowCount CDATA #REQUIRED
          fieldNames CDATA #REQUIRED
          type CDATA #IMPLIED>

<!ELEMENT field (null | boolean | number | dateTime | string | binary)*>
<!ATTLIST field
          name CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT binary (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST binary
          encoding CDATA #FIXED "base64"
          length CDATA #IMPLIED
          type CDATA #IMPLIED>
```